# Вывести категории подменю с изображениями

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Для вывода вывода основных категорий использую

```
<?php
$prod_cat_args = array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'orderby' => 'id', // здесь по какому полю сортировать
'hide_empty' => true, // скрывать категории без товаров или нет
'parent' => 0 // id родительской категории
);

$woo_categories = get_categories( $prod_cat_args );
foreach ( $woo_categories as $woo_cat ) {
$woo_cat_id = $woo_cat->term_id; //category ID
$woo_cat_name = $woo_cat->name; //category name
$woo_cat_slug = $woo_cat->slug; //category slug
echo '<div class="main-cat-item">';
$category_thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($woo_cat_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
$thumbnail_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail_id);
echo '<h2>';
echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $woo_cat_id, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $woo_cat_name . '</a>';
echo '</h2>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Куда мне вставить id подкатегори меню для вывода как тут https://minsktoys.by/

Answer (score 0):

В 'parent' => 0 // id родительской категории